# Serverless Database in C#

Tags: c#, database

Complete newbie question here: I'm just playing with C# for the first time and want to make a Windows Forms application which stores some info in a database structure, but obviously don't want to require something like MySQL to be installed on each client's computer. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use a database that doesn't require an install. There are a few out there - there's [Microsoft SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx), which frankly is badly named, as it won't support the more useful SQL functions like stored procedures, views and so on. There's also [VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net/) which does support stored procs, but requires purchase if you want Visual Studio plugins.

Answer (score 29):

You can use **SQLite**. It doesn't require any installation or server on the client's computers. Here is an [blog](http://www.mikeduncan.com/sqlite-on-dotnet-in-3-mins/) describing how to use it with .NET. It is easy to use, just add a reference to the **System.Data.SQLite.dll**.

Here is an open source data provider for .NET: [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

From [homepage](http://www.sqlite.org/): *"SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine. SQLite is the most widely deployed SQL database engine in the world. The source code for SQLite is in the public domain.*"

Comment: I can't recommend SQLite highly enough.

Comment: SQLite was terrible in my experience. Not recommended

Comment: I am currently using SQLite, but I'm going to have to move away from it because it doesn't support multiple simultaneous connections. I do love how it was just a file, and all that was needed to use it was the .dll. I'm going to look into MS SQL Server Compact, since it looks like the most similar one (serverless, installation-less, etc). If any one has any other suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: @Kousha You should explain why, instead of just saying it's terrible. I haven't had a single issue with it.

Comment: @Rob Yes it does accept multiple connects. https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

Comment: @B.K. I just mentioned it as a vote. Well, I used it for a simple web application as there were a few I/Os. The performance in a shared hosting was not satisfying at all. Multiple connections make it even slower. Also debugging was really tough. I switched to SQL CE, and the experience is not comparable at all. SQL CE runs wonderfully smooth.

Comment: @Kousha I see.  I'll check out SQL CE to see if there's any difference.  Thanks for the information.

Comment: use `sqlite-net` from nuget. But note, sqlite doesn't supports CONCURRENCY.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is Embedded Databases. You've got quite a large list of Embedded databases that you can use:

Commercial:

1. [VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net) - This database is written completely in managed C#.

Open Source:

1. Firebird - [.NET Driver](http://firebirdsql.org/dotnetfirebird/)
2. SQLite - [.NET Driver](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

Comment: Interesting- didn't know about Firebird.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your data to XML files, or you could take a look at the [Sql Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx).

You could also work with objects and serialize/deserialize these to disk as binaries.

Of course the type of storage you choose depends a lot on the kind of data you're storing (and the volume of it).

Answer (score 1):

Use [SQL Server CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it from .NET 3.5 onwards is to store your data in XML files and use [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). This allows you to use SQL-like commands on your data which are actually compiled into your application, so you get full IDE IntelliSense support and error checking.

Answer (score 1):

[VelocityDB](http://www.velocitydb.com) works in a server less mode but can also be combined with a server when there is a need for it. It outperforms all the other choices mentioned here by roughly a magnitude, see [comparison here](http://www.velocitydb.com/Compare.aspx). It allows you to use almost any .NET data structures persistently. The entire database engine and the optional server is implemented using C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could serialise a dataset and save it as XML. I'm a little confused why if you're playing around you would need to install MySQL on all client's computers. You could look at using SQL Express which is free perhaps?

Serialise Dataset:

http://blogs.msdn.com/yosit/archive/2003/07/10/9921.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163911.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest way will be SQL Server Compact, Because it integrates directly into the Visual Studio IDE (I'm just hazarding the guess here that you use VS). Add the "Local Database", Create your tables and be sure to make your Table Adapter with Select, Update, Insert and Delete methods. If during Database Creation you called your Dataset "DS" you will be able to instantiate a Table Adapter Object from

```
DSTableAdapters
```

Namespace, and Use GetData() or Fill() methods to retrieve your Data, and Insert(), Update() and Delete() to Manage it.