# How can I embed a MySQL database server inside a C# application?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Self-contained database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789908/self-contained-database)

I wish to create a C# application that embeds a MySQL database server. The data need to be stored in files and I need to access it inside the application, make queries and save results back to disk.

How might I approach this?

Comment: Is MySQL a requirement? If you just need a database, [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) is a perfect alternative for an in-app database.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968804/serverless-database-in-c-sharp

Comment: To start with, all databases stores its data in files. Secondly, how well have you searched, here or on Google? There are many example all over the Internet showing how to use MySQL (and a lot of other databases) out there.

Comment: @NewProger: You can roll back the edit if you wish; the user who make the edits is listed next to you badge underneath the question.

Comment: @Cory preferably, yes. But if the SQLite is more convinient I can switch.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg can you provide exact search term that you used? :)

Comment: Unfortunately I've never seen or heard of a wrapper that would allow MySQL to be serverless.

Comment: well i dont think he knows what he is asking. nothing related to SQLLite or any database kind.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: OP wants to embed a MySQL database (and the server required to access it) within their application. Yes, there are many resources on how to use MySQL, but virtually none on how to embed it within an application (it's likely not possible).

Comment: "mysql c#" or "mysql c# bindings" returns lots of hits on Google, many which leads back here to SO.

Comment: What necessary information do you feel was removed in the edit, NewProger?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg binding is not the same. I don't want to use external server... that's the problem. But I guess I will have to use SQLite then...

Comment: Yes, then SQLite is probably your only bet, as it's almost the only (and certainly the biggest) embeddable SQL solution available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. An Open Source ADO.NET provider **[SQLLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)** is the best Option for your scenario. Refer to this: [SQLLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

   - SQLite database engine is an ADO.NET 2.0/3.5 provider all rolled into a single mixed mode assembly.
   - System.Data.SQLite is the original [SQLLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database engine.
   - It is self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.
2. If you already have MySql database installed then you can embed it using MySql Connector. For detailed information you can go through this: [Connecting to MySQL Database using C# and .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71346/Connecting-to-MySQL-Database-using-C-and-NET)

Comment: SQLite is not a good idea. This dabatase dont have several commands like "Alter Table", "Drop Table", etc. Any change in the tables represents too much effort. Because you have to create new tables and delete the old.

Comment: Also, if you are using any kind of concurrency you'll regret the decision down the road. Even with WAL (write ahead logging) you will find it lacking when you get the constant "error: database is locked" messages.

Comment: yes true very true..i have been a latest victim of the error 'Database is locked'. After so much hard work and and hours of coding i had to abandon SQLite as backend for my c# win form project

Answer (score 3):

There's the [MySQL embedded library](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/libmysqld.html) called `libmysqld` but this is probably a lot more work to get going than SQLite. I'm not sure that there are native C# bindings, for one. It doesn't seem to be widely used. Generally an "embedded" MySQL is one bundled into an server appliance, not a compiled application that's distributed to third parties.

SQLite offers most of the basic features offered by MySQL and is designed to be low-impact on your application. You'll find it's almost the same under many use cases.

Comment: If I understand correctly using embedded MySQL needs commercial licence for non GPL compatible software.

Comment: @GrzegorzGierlik Another reason why SQLite is probably a better call. That one is public domain, so there's no issues.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, ADO.NET should work fine with MySQL. Try to have a look here:
http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlcsharptutorial/

Comment: You would still be required to install MySQL on the system running the application. MySQL is not a self-contained, stand-alone, serverless RDBMS like SQLite, Firebird, or Microsoft SQL Server CE.

Comment: That's the problem... If I needed to access the server it would be easy. But I wish that the aplication to be self contained and don't require external server or other stuff.